# Записать значения из двумерного массива в одномерный

Tags: php, массивы

Есть довольно тривиальный вопрос. Существует двумерный массив $polyclinic_doctors, его значения "id" мне нужно записать в новый массив - $doctors_id. Но записывается только последнее значение. В чём может быть проблема?

Результат dd($polyclinic_doctors):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
$doctors_id = [];    
foreach($polyclinic_doctors as $doctor){
    $doctors_id = $doctor["id"];
}
```

Результат dd($doctors_id):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `$doctors_id[] = $doctor["id"]`

Comment: @rusgeli , Laravel выдаёт ошибку Cannot use a scalar value as an array

Comment: Значит неправильно что-то сделал. Также можно использовать `array_column($polyclinic_doctors, 'id');`

Comment: @u_mulder , спасибо! Этот вариант помог